# how to get value from list in dart/flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get some currency data from a foreign exchange API. After getting data from the website,
I'm having a problem in extracting the desired value of currency pair from the list which I'm receiving after the HTTP request as data. Here's what I am doing:

```
Future<void> getInfo() async {
try {
  print((url));  //url = EUR/USD, this value is comeing from a dropdown
  URL =
      "https://fcsapi.com/api-v2/forex/latest?symbol=$url&access_key=t58zo1uMFJZlNJxSrSmZv2qIUlSkCk9RAfCLkwnMwt1q1FFS";
  print((URL));
  Response response =
      await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(URL),
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

  data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data);

  List info = data['response'];
  print(info);
  
  double price = ......; // I don't know what to write here I have tried everything.
  print(price);
```

here I want to get the value of the price  from the list "info" but idont know what to write in 'double price'

```
} catch (e) {
  print('error is : $e');
}
}
```

this is the result on consol

```
I/flutter ( 4286): EUR/USD
I/flutter ( 4286): https://fcsapi.com/api-v2/forex/latest? 
symbol=EUR/USD&access_key=t58zo1uMFJZlNJxSrSmZv2qIUlSkCk9RAfCLkwnMwt1q1FFS

I/flutter ( 4286): {status: true, code: 200, msg: Successfully,
                   response: [{
                               id: 1,
                               price: 1.1788, 
                               change: +0.0072,
                               chg_per: +0.61%, 
                               last_changed: 2020-10-05 14:47:57, 
                               symbol: EUR/USD}], 
                               info: {server_time: 2020-10-05 14:49:12 UTC,
                               credit_count: 1, _t: 2020-10-05 14:49:12 UTC}}
   
        // this is printing due to print (data); statemet

 I/flutter ( 4286): [{
                       id: 1, 
                       price: 1.1788, // i want to print this value
                       change: +0.0072, 
                       chg_per: +0.61%, 
                       last_changed: 2020-10-05 14:47:57, 
                       symbol: EUR/USD}]

       // this is printing due to print (info); statemet, which is printing the responce of json
```

what i want :

i want to print the value of price in console after printing the responce e.g.

```
     I/flutter ( 4286): 1.1788
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
double price = info[0]['price']
```

Answer (score 0):

since the response is a list / array, you can use index to get items from the list.

```dart
var item = info[0]; // get first item from the list.
double price = item["price"];
print(price);
```